# How do I determine the number of days per month between 2 dates on Excel 2016 with a formula?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016

I am trying to identify the number of days per month between 2 specific dates which happen to not start and end in on the 1st and 31st of their respective months. For example, if the dates were 5/01/2023 and 17/03/2023, I would like to form a formula which would give me the results of 26 for January, 28 for February and 17 for March. I also need this to be a non-VBA solution.

[image: A snapshot of what I need]

I have tried a couple of simple if formulas but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The formula below works for the data in your screenshot

```
=IF(EOMONTH(INDEX($B$2:$B$8,MATCH(B$11,$A$2:$A$8,0)),-1)+1=$A12,EOMONTH($A12,0)-INDEX($B$2:$B$8,MATCH(B$11,$A$2:$A$8,0)),
IF(EOMONTH(INDEX($C$2:$C$8,MATCH(B$11,$A$2:$A$8,0)),-1)+1=$A12,DAY(INDEX($C$2:$C$8,MATCH(B$11,$A$2:$A$8,0))),
IF(AND($A12<INDEX($C$2:$C$8,MATCH(B$11,$A$2:$A$8,0)),$A12>INDEX($B$2:$B$8,MATCH(B$11,$A$2:$A$8,0))),EOMONTH($A12,0)-$A12+1,"")))
```

[image: screenshot illustrating suggested formula]

(the dates in cells `A12:A25` are all the 1st of the month, formatted with the `mmmm dddd` custom number formatting)